# Добавление кнопки в таблицу Django Admin

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

Мне нужно добавить кнопку в колонку таблицы Django Admin которая  будет удалять запись. Кнопка должна быть у каждой записи.

**models.py**

```
class Worker (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField ('Name', max_length=30)
    surname = models.CharField ('Surname', max_length=30)
```

**admin.py**

```
class WorkerAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('surname', 'name')
    search_fields = ('surname', 'name')
    list_filter = ('surname', 'name')

admin.site.register(Worker, WorkerAdmin)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

@admin.register(Worker)
class WorkerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('surname', 'name', 'remove_button')
    search_fields = ('surname', 'name')
    list_filter = ('surname', 'name')

    def remove_button(self, obj):
        return '<a class="button" href="{}">Delete</a>'.format(reverse('admin:workers_worker_delete', args=[obj.pk]))
    remove_button.short_description = ''
    remove_button.allow_tags = True
```

Comment: выдает ошибку 
`NoReverseMatch at /admin/zpapp/worker/
Reverse for 'workers_worker_delete' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

Comment: Поменяйте `admin:workers_worker_delete` на `admin:zpapp_worker_delete`

Comment: Огромное спасибо!